# JQuery not working in click listener

Tags: jquery

i have following button:

```
<button type="button" class="start-upload-btn">Start Uploading</button>
```

I'm adding a click listener to it within the script tags:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert(jQuery);
    $('.start-upload-btn').on('click', function() {
        alert(jQuery);
        var myData = ${dataForUpload};
        if (myData) {
            $.each($.parseJSON(myData), function(key,value){
                alert(value.oldFile);
            });
        }
        else {
            alert('No Data');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The **alert(JQuery);** within the click function does not work on clicking. I can't figure out what's the matter with my code.

**Update:** i'm using this cdn for JQuery in head.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've updated my code with ready function, but it still isn't working.

Comment: You need to put your jQuery code inside a DOMReady handler: `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: It working fine check http://jsfiddle.net/26zuxks9/

Comment: yeah but not in my files

Answer (score 1):

Write your code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){----}
```

and instead of using alert(jQuery) use debugger;